# Do the topologies of pointwise and compact convergence coincide on equicontinuous subsets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

If $E$ is a set, then the topology $\rho(E)$ generated by $$p_x(f):=|f(x)|\;\;\;\text{for }f:E\to\mathbb R$$ for $x\in E$ is called the *topology of pointwise convergence on $\mathbb R^E$*. If $\tau$ is a topology on $E$, then the topology $\kappa(E,\tau)$ generated by $$p_K(f):=\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C(E,\tau)$$ for $\tau$-compact $K\subseteq E$ is called the *topology of compact convergence on $C(E,\tau)$*.

> Are we able to show that if $\Gamma\subseteq C(E,\tau)$ is $\tau$-equicontinuous, then$^1$ $\left.\rho(E)\right|_\Gamma=\left.\kappa(E,\tau)\right|_\Gamma$? If not, what do we need to assume to show that?

Moreover, I would like to know how exactly we can show that $$\kappa(E,\tau)\subseteq\left.\rho(E)\right|_{C(E,\:\tau)}\tag1.$$

*Remark*: I know that generally, if $X$ is a vector space and $\sigma$ is the topology generated by a family $P$ of seminorms on $X$, then $$\mathcal B_P:=\left\{\varepsilon\bigcap_{p\in F}U_p:F\subseteq P\text{ is finite and }\varepsilon>0\right\}$$ is an analytic basis for $\sigma$, where $$U_p:=\{x\in X:p(x)<1\}\;\;\;\text{for }p\in P.$$ This should be helpful to know.

---

$^1$ If $(X,\sigma)$ is a topological space and $B\subseteq X$, then $\left.\sigma\right|_B:=\{O\cap B:O\in\sigma\}$ denotes the subspace topology on $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space,  $M$ be a metric space, and $E$ be an equicontinuous set of functions from $X$ to $M$.
Also let $D$ be a dense subset of $X$.
Then the following three topologies coincide on $E$:

1. The topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $X$,
2. The topology of pointwise convergence on $X$,
3. The topology of pointwise convergence on $D$.
   In order to verify this assertion it suffices to prove that if $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a net in $E$,  and if $f\in  E$,  then the
   following are equivalent:

a. $\displaystyle\lim_{i\to \infty }\sup_{x\in  K}d\big (f_i(x), f(x)\big )=0$,  for every compact subset $K\subseteq X$,

b. $\displaystyle\lim_{i\to \infty }f_i(x)=f(x)$,  for every $x\in  X$,

c. $\displaystyle\lim_{i\to \infty }f_i(x)=f(x)$,  for every $x\in  D$.

It is evident that (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b) $\Rightarrow$ (c), so we only need to worry about
(c) $\Rightarrow$ (a).

In order to do this,  given any compact subset $K\subseteq X$, and any $\varepsilon >0$,  using equicontinuity,  for
each $x$ in $K$,   we choose a neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that
$$
    y\in V_x\Rightarrow d\big (g(x),g(y)\big )<\varepsilon, \quad\forall g\in  E.
      $$
Since $K$ is compact and $\{V_x\}_{x\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, we may find $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n\in K$ such that
$$
  K\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^nV_{x_j}.
    $$
Since $D$ is dense in $X$, for every $j$ we may pick some $y_j\in D\cap V_{x_j}$.    Using (c) let $i_0\in I$, such that
$$
  i\geq i_0\Rightarrow d\big (f_i(y_j), f(y_j)\big )<\varepsilon , \quad\forall j=1,\ldots ,n.
    $$
Next, given any $i\geq i_0$, and any $x$ in $K$, pick $j$ such that $x\in V_{x_j}$.  Then
$$
d\big (f_i(x),f(x)\big ) \leq $$$$\leq
  d\big (f_i(x),f_i(x_j)\big ) +  
  d\big (f_i(x_j),f_i(y_j)\big ) +  
   d\big (f_i(y_j), f(y_j)\big ) + $$$$+
   d\big (f(y_j), f(x_j) \big ) +
   d\big (f(x_j), f(x) \big ) < 
   5\varepsilon .
    $$
Consequently
$$
\sup_{x\in  K}d\big (f_i(x), f(x)\big )\leq 5\varepsilon ,
  $$
for all $i\geq i_0$.

Comment: When you write "it suffices to prove", do you've got the following in mind: If $E$ is a set and  $\tau_i$ is a topology on $E$ such that every net has a $\tau_1$-limit point if and only if it has a $\tau_2$-limit, then $\tau_1=\tau_2$?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure whether this is correct or it needs to be stated in the following way instead: If $E$ is a set and  $\tau_i$ is a topology on $E$ such that for every net $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$ it holds that $x$ is a $\tau_1$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$ if and only if $x$ is a $\tau_2$-limit of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$, then $\tau_1=\tau_2$?

Comment: (The difference is that in the former characterization, it might be that the $\tau_1$-limit point and the $\tau_2$-limit may be different)

Comment: I'm sure that in either case, we would derive this characterization from the fact that if $B\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$, then $x\in\overline B$ if and only if there is a net converging to $x$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, two topologies coincide iff the identity map from one to the other, and vice versa, are continuous.  To check for continuity one needs only prove sequencial continuity (with nets, of course) and that is precisely what I've done.

Comment: Yes, I see, but I'd still be interested in that question. Is it possible that it holds "every net has a $\tau_1$-limit point iff it has a $\tau_2$-limit point", but $\tau_1\ne\tau_2$? (I stress again that, at first glance, the stated assertion is not equivalent to "for every $x\in E$ and every net $(x_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq E$, it holds that $x$ is a $\tau_1$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$ iff $x$ is a $\tau_2$-limit point of $(x_t)_{t\in I}$".)

Comment: Sounds like a pretty nice excuse for starting another post!

Comment: I think you need to fix your $\varepsilon$ calculation at the end of your answer, since you're going the path over the dense set: You only have $d(f(y_j),f(x))\le d(f(y_j),f(x_j))+d(f(x_j),f(x))<\frac23\varepsilon$ (not "$<\frac13\varepsilon$"). And the same applies to $d(f_i(y_j),f_i(x))<\frac23$. Oh, and you've written $V_j$ instead of $V_{x_j}$ at the end.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but if $E$ is a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, then the topology of pointwise convergence on $E'$ is precisely the weak* topology $\sigma(E',E)$. Is $\sigma(E',E)$ weaker or stronger than the topology of compact convergence on $E'$? Can we somehow answer this question using the arguments in your answer?